# HTML content inside a really tall div

Tags: html, css, browser

I'd like to create a web page with a really, really large scrollable content area.

However it seems like once the size gets too large browsers stop displaying the full content area correctly. e.g.

```
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="visCont">
    <img src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/5a0399bd8948116a5c05be65/master/w_644,c_limit/kaley-cuoco-the-big-bang-theory-penny-season-11-2017.jpg"> </img>
  </div>
  <div id="invisibleContent">
    <p>
    text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

#scrollable {
  overflow-y:auto;
}

#visCont {
   top: 6710000px;
  position:absolute;
}

#invisibleContent {
  top: 6720000px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Here if you scroll all the way to the bottom you will see the image and the text displayed fine at the bottom of the div:

https://jsfiddle.net/L7c8bmpm/11/

However here because the content is so far down from the top, the the text is cut off in Chrome, and you don't even get the white div background at the bottom. In IE, it seems like the text isn't displayed and the image is at the very bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/ww5yu6nh/10/

is there a way to fix this? or is this just a limitation of most web browsers these days as it's not expected that anyone would need a div this tall?

Comment: In your second example the text is not cut off for me. The image is also visible but it is positioned 1000px from the bottom due to the different values that you have used for `top`. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here but the whole concept seems strange.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132. Your OS? Your browser version? Also: `<img />` tags are standalone...

Comment: using Windows 10. using Chrome 65.0.3325.181. and tried IE 11.125.16299

Answer (score 0):

It should all render fine and in my browser (Chrome v65) I can see both elements just fine, but I think your approach is wrong.
Your parent div with id scrollable has a `height` of `0`. Because the elements within are positioned `absolute` they receive their own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and the parent div collapses. The scrollbar you currently see is actually on the `body`.

A better approach would be this:

```
#scrollable {
    height: 6720000px;
    position: relative;
}
#visCont {
    bottom: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
}
#invisibleContent {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afe6odw3/1/

The scrollbar is still on the body, but your parent div does have an actual height now.

Comment: getting the same problem, content getting cut off at the bottom.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afe6odw3/2/ I've added a background. Because the body has a margin by default, you should see a white border at the bottom. I just checked, the window in jsFiddle stops rendering with me at 16.777.200 pixels, but it will show the rest as blank. Does this happen with you? Can you scroll past it and see a blank page?

Comment: Ha! Fun! Checked the max possible height of the body outside of jsFiddle. And it does some strange rendering after that threshold of 16.777.200 pixels.

Comment: It seems it's not really the height of the body, because any background-color applied to the body still renders, but any element put in the body can't be higher than 16.777.200 pixels

Comment: yep, in Chrome it just doesn't render stuff after a certain point. On my actual page, if I click onto blank space where my content should be, my javascript code registers the click for the div which is supposed to be in that blank spot, so it does seem to be some kind of a rendering issue. In IE and Edge it seems that the div just doesn't grow past a certain size, and all the content that's supposed to be placed beyond that size get squashed.

Comment: Firefox and IE just seem to stop rendering past the last static or relative positioned element in the container when the height gets too big. Only Safari seems to be rendering past a large number.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code try this one
this is only an example
note  tag is no close

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.image{

     /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}


    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <img src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/5a0399bd8948116a5c05be65/master/w_644,c_limit/kaley-cuoco-the-big-bang-theory-penny-season-11-2017.jpg" class="image">


    <p>
    text
    </p>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the image and the text are at the top of the page